# Localizing a sideloaded app in WinRT

Tags: localization, windows-runtime

I have a WinRT app which I have localized strings for in .resw resource files.  When I launch the app through the debugger to test it both languages work, however when I sideload the app by using the VS generated powershell script only the en-US language works.  I'm using [this method](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8368f95d-891f-4d0c-a1a9-a08c8d5f4352/sideloaded-app-can-not-change-language-programmatically?forum=winappswithcsharp) to change the language dynamically during runtime.

What should I do in order to fix this? Any place I should look for errors like this?

---

Additional Details:

- The build action for the resource files is set to PRIResource
- Both files are contained in the standard Strings\\resources.resw path
- I have my app manifest set to always generate an app bundle
- My Package.appxmanifest lists out both languages, I've tried this as well as leaving it on x-generate

```
<Resources>
  <Resource Language="es-419" />
  <Resource Language="en-US" />
</Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set languages in control panel

A packaged app can only access languages for which Windows has available as a language preference from within the control panel.

### Make sure resources are reloaded properly

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8368f95d-891f-4d0c-a1a9-a08c8d5f4352/sideloaded-app-can-not-change-language-programmatically?forum=winappswithcsharp) is some additional information on how to rest the resource context after changing the PrimaryLanguageOverride